# Setting a NSMutableAttributedString left aligned and right aligned text

Tags: objective-c, text-alignment, nsmutableattributedstring

I am attempting to use NSMutableAttributedString to format text to be left aligned and right aligned on the same piece of text

I've reviewed a similar answer at [IOS Multiple right and left align on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617365/ios-multiple-right-and-left-align-on-same-line)  but could not get the tab stops to work correctly.

My own solution is to do the following.

Have my copy + add physical tabs (ie: `\t`) to the end of the copy

Then create a paragraph style for my chat time string which is right aligned and append this to the end of the string.

I've almost got it to work;

[image]

But the problem is the time isn't right aligned at all; it seems to be stuck left aligned.

I'd like the time text to be on the right hand side.

Here is my code for setting up the time part;

```
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message.body attributes:attributes];

NSMutableAttributedString *finalizedCopy = [attributedString mutableCopy];
    if (message.sender.remoteID) [finalizedCopy appendAttributedString:tabStops];


    // Add time to the chat bubble
    NSString *messageTime = [[JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter sharedFormatter] timeForDate:message.date];
    NSAttributedString *chatMessageTime = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:messageTime attributes:attributes];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *timeParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    timeParagraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    NSMutableAttributedString *dateString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:chatMessageTime];
    [dateString setAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont vic_fontOfSize:10],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor vic_darkTextColor]
                                 }
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, dateString.length)];

    [dateString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:timeParagraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, dateString.length)];

    [finalizedCopy appendAttributedString:dateString];


    attributedString = [finalizedCopy copy];
```

I am wondering how to best achieve the desired effect.

Many thanks

Also, if I were to use NSTabStops -- where do I put them, at the end of my left-hand string or at the start of my right-hand string?

ie:

`NSTextTab *tabStop = [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight location:150 options:nil];
        [paragraph setTabStops:@[tabStop]];
        [finalizedCopy addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraph range:NSMakeRange(0, finalizedCopy.length)];`

Is at the end of my left-hand string but I see no results visually.

Comment: Have you tried two labels and autolayout ? I know its not direct answer to your question, but just a suggestion.

Comment: I can't do that because I will be expected to pass in the attributedString into a JSQMessage podfile and return this;   `return [[VICChatMessage alloc] initWithAttributedText:attributedString sender:senderID date:message.date];}`

Answer (score 3):

Here's some generic Swift code that does what you want I think.  The same approach should work in Objective-C as well:

```
    // Paragraph with left and right aligned text

let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .left
for tabStop in paragraph.tabStops {
    paragraph.removeTabStop(tabStop)
}
paragraph.addTabStop(NSTextTab(textAlignment: .right, location: 240.0, options: [:]))

let text = NSMutableAttributedString()

let leftAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph
]

let rightAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph
]

let data = [
    "Carrots": 23,
    "Pears": 453,
    "Apples ": 2350
]

for (key, value) in data {
    text.append(NSAttributedString(string: key, attributes: leftAttributes))
    text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\t\(value)\n", attributes: rightAttributes))
}
```