# Attributed text in swift with line alignment

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I have a label that has attributed text. I want to achieve something look like this image.
[sample label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI4WY.png)

*Subcategory* and *price* text should be left and right alignment respectively and in a single line. There is some space before *Subcategory* text.
Please provide any sample code for this kind of attributed text.

Comment: I tried to append text  as new line but cannot  append text  as left and right alignment text in a single line.

Comment: Can you do this in a table view. That will be much easier.

Comment: this label is actually in a table view cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSMutableAttributedString add different alignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737503/nsmutableattributedstring-add-different-alignments)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617365/ios-multiple-right-and-left-align-on-same-line But if it's a cell, clearly two UILabel would be easier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let myLabelWidth = 300
let myLabelHeight = 50

let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.tabStops = [
    NSTextTab(textAlignment: .right, location: CGFloat(myLabelWidth), options: [:]),
]

let attributed = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Subcategory 1\t$30",
    attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraph]
)

// Change 'x' value to "some" space before the text
let myLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                    y: 0,
                                    width: myLabelWidth,
                                    height: myLabelHeight))

// Just added to see boundaries of the view that contains the text
myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
myLabel.attributedText = attributed
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a paragraph style and add a head indent.

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.headIndent = 100 // your value here
```

Then add the paragraph style as the attribute.

```
[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
```

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
[NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style]
```